# Ant based build: How to pass argument to the jar tool?

Tags: eclipse, jar, ant, build.xml

Inheriting a project whose `build.xml` produces a `.ear` final product, I now need to pass a ["-P"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u80-relnotes-2494162.html) command line option to the [jar tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html), as explained in 7u80 Update Release Notes:

> Starting with JDK 7u79 release, the **jar** tool no longer allows the
>   leading slash "/" and ".." (dot-dot) path component in zip entry file
>   name when creating new and/or extracting from zip and jar file. If
>   needed, the new command line option **"-P"** should be used explicitly to
>   preserve the dot-dot and/or absolute path component.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The Ant `jar` task doesn't use the `jar` tool, it builds the jar directly using the Java jar file APIs.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 -- that explains why I was having such hard time figuring out how to implement Oracle's suggestion. Any idea how to accomplish the "-P" option with the Ant jar? Or is it a lost cause? (currently, my workaround is build with an older update of JDK 7 (e.g. 7u45)).

Comment: If you need functionality not provided by the `jar` task, your only option is to use `exec` or `apply` and run the actual jar executable.

Comment: The changes to the jar utility are implemented in the Main class, not in the low-level Jar and Zip classes that are used directly by Ant jar task.  Therefore, if this change is affecting your build, the build must be running the jar tool directly.  Can you check?

Comment: @martinclayton Thanks for this extra insight. It turns out that my problem stemmed from a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44256470/8080472) -- now solved. If Oracle's new `jar` tool only **restricts** from now on lading slash and dot-dot, I believe this shouldn't be a problem for the older Ant-based jar. Therefore, the answer to my question is most likely: "No, there is no way to do that -- and it does not matter". Please confirm in an answer that I can upvote and accept. Thanks.