# ClassNotFoundException dependent on JDK7 update version only?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, classnotfoundexception, ear

I inherited a JBOSS 4.2.3.GA .`ear` project in which everything loads and runs fine if I build it with JDK 7u45, but fails to load & run early in the JBoss Bootstrap if I build it with any newer update of JDK 7 (e.g. 7u76, 7u79, 7u80).

The JBOSS server itself runs on Java 1.7.0_45.

The logged reason for the failure is a ClassNofFoundException for a class that is actually there (even for the failing .ear):

```
log4j:ERROR Could not create the Layout. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbs.common.logger.CsvLayout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:178)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseLayout(DOMConfigurator.java:555)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:269)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:999)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:901)
        at org.jboss.logging.Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask.reconfigure(Log4jService.java:643)
        at org.jboss.logging.Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask.run(Log4jService.java:582)
        at org.jboss.logging.Log4jService.setup(Log4jService.java:460)
        at org.jboss.logging.Log4jService.createService(Log4jService.java:476)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:260)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.create(ServiceController.java:330)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.create(ServiceController.java:273)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:260)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Normally, I would easily find a [real](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/javalangclassnotfoundexception-how-to.html) reason for a ClassNofFoundException, but this time I am baffled, considering the following facts:

1. The entire environment (including the **CLASSPATH**!) for the `.ear` is **identical**.
2. The aforementioned "not found class" dbs.common.logger.CsvLayout **is in** the common.jar file in exactly the same path where it is supposed to be.
3. There are no errors in the build whatsoever.
4. On someone else's development workstation (same Eclipse, etc.) building that `.ear` with JDK 7u79 (i.e. later update than 7u45), results in a .ear that properly loads and runs (on same server and environment).

**What could possibly explain such ClassNofFoundException?**

What am I missing?

---

**Update:**
Comparing the "not found" CsvLayout.class between the working and not working common.jar file, shows that there is a difference in the major_version of the [class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html). The working one has `0x33` (Java SE 7), the failing has `0x34` (Java SE 8).

I have been careful to always work with *Execution Environments* that are jre7 only. How did that `0x34` sneak in?

Comment: what major versions di you see? Java 7 should have 51.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I have just updated my question to include the answer to your question. This is very weird: I *am* running Eclipse under Java 8, but I made sure to select only execution environments that use Java 7. Have I missed an Eclipse/build.xml configuration feature that excludes the "ambient" Java from the actual build?

Comment: how and where is common.jar built? Make sure that the jar is compiled to have Java7 level. the argument for `javac` would be `-target 1.7` in a maven project this would be the property         `<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`. Explicitly configure it for 7, otherwise the compiler will use target version 8 when running under Java8. This is not a problem of execution environment but of the build environment

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I suspected it was the **build** environment. Using `ant` (build.xml), not maven (pom.xml). How do I explicitly configure it to 7?

Comment: Take a look http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: sorry for not answering earlier, just use the doc @FedericoSierra was referring to, you'll need the `target` attribute.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks to your guidance, I solved the problem by adding the following lines to the build.xml:  ``<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/>
 <property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7"/>`` Please post your comments as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the library *common.jar*: is built using java 8 without specifying the target classfile version, and so a jar file with java 8 class file versions is generated.

To build Java 7 classfile with Java 8 you need to

- pure java compilation: add the target option `javac -target 1.7 <javafile>`
- maven: add the property `<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>`
- ant: add `<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/> <property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7"/>`to your build.xml